# SAS enterprise guide DF of 0 and B when adding combined variables

Tags: sas, regression

I'm trying to get the relativity of cost between different ages and genders. So the final results should show that as age increases, the cost increases. After creating dummy variables, I used the following codes in SAS:

```
proc reg data= data1; model logDollar= M0 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10 M11 M12 M13 M14 M15 M16 M17 M18 M19 M20 M21 M22 M24 
M25 M26 M27 M28 M29 M30 M31 M32 M33 M34 M35 M36 M37 M38 M39 M40 M41 M42 M43 M44 M45 M46 M47 M48 M49 M50 M51 
M52 M53 M54 M55 M56 M57 M58 M59 M60 F0 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 F10 F11 F12 F13 
F14 F15 F16 F17 F18 F19 F20 F21 F22 F23 F24 F25 F26 F27 F28 F29 F30 F31 F32 F33 F34 F35 F36 F37 F38 F39 F40 
F41 F42 F43 F44 F45 F46 F47 F48 F49 F50 F51 F52 F53 F54 F55 F56 F57 F58 F59 F60

  ;
weight membership;
run;
```

The codes above work fine. My next step is to remove the noise. For example, people in the east side of town tends to cost more, and I don't want that to be reflected in the curve. So then I added new variables to the codes:

```
model logDollar= M0 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10 M11 M12 M13 M14 M15 M16 M17 M18 M19 M20 M21 M22 M24 
M25 M26 M27 M28 M29 M30 M31 M32 M33 M34 M35 M36 M37 M38 M39 M40 M41 M42 M43 M44 M45 M46 M47 M48 M49 M50 M51 
M52 M53 M54 M55 M56 M57 M58 M59 M60 F0 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 F10 F11 F12 F13 
F14 F15 F16 F17 F18 F19 F20 F21 F22 F23 F24 F25 F26 F27 F28 F29 F30 F31 F32 F33 F34 F35 F36 F37 F38 F39 F40 
F41 F42 F43 F44 F45 F46 F47 F48 F49 F50 F51 F52 F53 F54 F55 F56 F57 F58 F59 F60

HealthyEast
HealthyNorth
HealthyWest

UnhealthyEast
UnhealthyNorth
UnhealthyWest
UnhealthySouth

;
weight membership;
run;
```

Now my model is showing DF=0 for those new variables. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Following is part of the result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5ixg.jpg)

Comment: That's a huge number of dummy variables. Can you give us a sample dataset in `datalines` format? It's hard to know why there are 0 degrees of freedom for these new variables without making the assumption that your p > n. Additionally, I would recommend using something like `proc mixed` or `glmselect` instead of `proc reg`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added a picture of part of the result. I'm brand new to sas and regression. My colleague tried glm for me but it didn't work. So I was hoping to stick with what I have now . Is there a way to stick with proc reg and still fix the issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You really, really should not have a dummy variable for each age. Instead, treat age as continuous variable. Also, How are `HealthyWest` and `UnhealthyWest` calculated? Are they the exact opposite? If so you won't get estimates for those either.

Your model should likely be:

```
proc glm data=have;
class sex healthyEast healthyNorth healthyWest;
model logDollar= sex age sex*age
HealthyEast
HealthyNorth
HealthyWest
;
weight membership;
run;
```

Sex would be M/F, Age would be a numeric field and HealthEast/North/West would be binary categorical data.